# Python requests post body

Tags: python, request, python-requests

i am trying to send sql query to my wordpress database using adminer script but the problem im missing somthing needed to be sent as body or headers in my opinion ( if i'm wrong please connect me )

**Request raw**

```
POST /REV/adminer-4.7.5-en.php?server=localhost&username=adepfran_wp975&db=adepfran_wp975&sql=select%20*%20from%20wplj_users HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://mywebsite/REV/adminer-4.7.5-en.php?server=localhost&username=adepfran_wp975&db=adepfran_wp975&sql=
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1328964205768204682490124619

Content-Length: 425
Cookie: adminer_sid=00e0c898e031284904f8e51b591c1dee; adminer_key=320bc6e9870ffdf2f54982cb2292de87
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"

select * from wplj_users
-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="limit"


-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

401937:659783
-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619--
```

**Headers raw**

```
-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"

select * from wplj_users
-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="limit"

-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

401937:659783
-----------------------------1328964205768204682490124619--
```

also i intercepted the requests using Burp Suite to clarify further

**Request raw**

[image: Request raw]

**Request parameters**

[image: Request parameters]

**Request Headers**

[image: Request parameters]

my actual code

```
ses = requests.Session()
                    data = {"server": "localhost",
                           "username": wpuser,
                           "db": wpdb,
                            "sql": "SELECT * from wplj_users"}
                    url="https://mywebsite/REV/adminer-4.7.5-en.php?server=localhost&username=adepfran_wp975&db=adepfran_wp975&sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20wplj_users"
                    request = ses.post(url,data=data )
```

the request without limit,query,token (Content-Disposition) does not return the wanted response , how can i pass them  ?

Comment: can't you connect directly to database and send query using some of MySQL module?

Comment: if you want to uses requests then maybe first send `GET` to main page to get fresh cookies and fresh session ID - and Session() will automatically add it to `POST`. If normally you have to login to adminer then your code has to also login to adminer.

Comment: it looks like you may have to send it as `files=`, not as `data=`

Comment: thats a part of my code i have already connected in the adminer and tested the session cookies the major problem i want to send this `------WebKitFormBoundaryyxYbgqzZBgPMzQXH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"

select * from wplj_termmeta
------WebKitFormBoundaryyxYbgqzZBgPMzQXH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="limit"


------WebKitFormBoundaryyxYbgqzZBgPMzQXH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

792550:799199
------WebKitFormBoundaryyxYbgqzZBgPMzQXH--`

Comment: you have to send it as `requests.post(..., files={"sql": "select * from wplj_termmeta", ...})`

Comment: the name is query why you passed it as "sql" , for exemple for token what sould i put

Comment: I used your code - so I would ask why do you use `sql` instead of `query` in `data=`? But you are right it has to be `query`.

Comment: first I would GET main page and I would search this token in HTML or in cookies and copy it to `files={"token": ...}`

Comment: when i sent request and captured it there is both the sql in in the `data` and the `query` `limit ` &  `token  ` in the Request payload  or raw data i dont know what is exactly is called here is a screenshot to explain more http://prntscr.com/qii0px

Comment: `Query String` means elements in url `adminer-4.7.5-en.php?sql=...` which you can set manually in url or using `post(..., params={"sql": ...})` . `Payload` means elements send in body using `data=`, or `json=` or `files=`

Comment: There were empty lines which were obviously incorrect. I tried to trim them, but I may have been overzealous. Please review.

Comment: tripleee the problem is already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to send it as `files=`

For test I used https://httpbin.org which send back all what you get in requests so I can display it and compare with expected data

In files I used `(None, "SELECT * from wplj_users")` so this `None` will remove `filename="query"`

```
import requests

params = {
    'server': 'localhost',
    'username': 'adepfran_wp975',
    'db': 'adepfran_wp975',
    'sql': 'SELECT * from wplj_users',
   }

data = {
    "query": (None, "SELECT * from wplj_users"),
    "limit": (None, ""),
    "token": (None, "401937:659783"),
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    #'Referer': 'https://mywebsite/REV/adminer-4.7.5-en.php?server=localhost&username=adepfran_wp975&db=adepfran_wp975&sql='

    # requests.Session() should care of cookies so this header shouldn't be needed
    #'Cookie': 'adminer_sid=00e0c898e031284904f8e51b591c1dee; adminer_key=320bc6e9870ffdf2f54982cb2292de87'
}

url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
#url = "https://mywebsite/REV/adminer-4.7.5-en.php"

s = requests.Session()
#r = s.get(url) # to get fresh cookies
r = s.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, files=data)

print('\n=== url ===\n')
print(r.request.url)

print('\n=== headers ===\n')
for key, val in r.request.headers.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, val))

print('\n=== body ===\n')
print(r.request.body.decode())
```

Results

```
=== url ===

https://httpbin.org/post?server=localhost&username=adepfran_wp975&db=adepfran_wp975&sql=SELECT+%2A+from+wplj_users

=== headers ===

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 331
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=79f18e4306b943ea92a49bae21b51b9c

=== body ===

--79f18e4306b943ea92a49bae21b51b9c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"

SELECT * from wplj_users
--79f18e4306b943ea92a49bae21b51b9c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="limit"


--79f18e4306b943ea92a49bae21b51b9c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

401937:659783
--79f18e4306b943ea92a49bae21b51b9c--
```